# LNK2019 Despite the contents of code (Visual Studio 2013, C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have recently updated to Visual Studio 2013, and to avoid the known problems with uninstalling one of the two programs (I previously used 2010) while the other is installed I uninstalled 2010 before I installed 2013.

Despite what code I place in it, even simple code that is only a few lines, Everything gets this LNK2019 error.

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Testing" << endl;


        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Before anyone comments with the "Do not use system("pause")" I know this and I did it purely for simplicity reasons to see if the code would even compile as it would not with any of my longer code either.

Here is a copy of the Error message.

> Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *WinMain@16 referenced in >function _*_tmainCRTStartup    C:\Users\z49203\Documents\Visual Studio >2013\Projects\JCCNEW\JCCNEW\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj)   JCCNEW

As for extensions in Visual Studio, I have the English version of it with the Japanese language pack. As I need to be able to code using both character sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your project a Console application not a Window Form one. Otherwise the program needs a `WinMain` as entry point instead of `main`.